# Cypher: using OPTIONAL MATCH in combination with collect returns default item when there is none

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4J to retrieve a person and their skills. This is my Cypher query:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: "1"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p) -[exp:HAS_EXPERIENCE]->(s:Skill)
WITH collect(distinct {id: s.id, name: s.name}) as skills, p

RETURN p.id as id, skills
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "skills": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "id": null,
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the list of skills contains a 'default' item. However, in this particular case the person has no skills.

Why does the result contain an array item? How to I adjust the query so that an empty array is returned?

Using Neo4J 3.1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: "1"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[exp:HAS_EXPERIENCE]->(s:Skill)
RETURN p.id AS id,
  CASE WHEN s IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT(distinct {id: s.id, name: s.name}) END as skills;
```

`s` would only be `NULL` if the `OPTIONAL MATCH` does not match anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider the following:

```
MATCH (p:Person {id: "1"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p) -[exp:HAS_EXPERIENCE]->(s:Skill)

RETURN p {id: p.id, skills: COLLECT(distinct s {.*})}
```

Assuming that you wish to get all fields from the **Skill**. Otherwise

```
... collect(distinct s {id:s.id, name:s.name})
```

Comment: Much better than accepted answer. Do not forgot to include `s` after `DISTINCT`. Without that `s` it would still return default values.